# WRT160Nv3 Linksys router running v3.0.03 firmware webinterface becomes unavailable

Tags: networking, router, timeout

We have the latest firmware and have 20mbit up and 20mbit down internet. We have about 20 devices connected with utp and some wifi. After a while the web interface (192.168.1.1) becomes unavailable (times out) but we still have internet connection, however it is really slow. The LAN (accessing shared folder across LAN) works fine!

When I unplug the powercord and switch it back on, it all works fine again. also the web interface is responding fast.

Can this have anything to do with our Gigaset N300A IP( running latest firmware) in the LAN? We cannot live without VoIP, so I cannot test it. Or is it possible that users download torrents which create a lot of connections which flood the router?

Answer (score 1):

It does sound like someone is hogging your bandwidth. A simple way to check whether this is indeed the case, and to correct the situtation, is explained below. Should this fail, do keep in mind that there are also other possibilities like mis-configuration of your LAN/WAN, problems with your ISP, and so on.

Your router supports QoS (I just checked the online manual [here](http://support.linksys.com/en-us/support/routers/WRT160N)). QoS is an option which allows you to control the priority given to different kinds of activities, like VoIP (to which you may assign the highest priority), gaming, torrents, and so on. You may wish to experiment with this, for instance by assigning impossibly low priorities to such activities as you see fit, and check whether this reduces the problem of your connections. If it does, then you know which kind of activity is bringing your system to a halt, and you may establish harsh, but at least not unrealistic priorities for your system.

Your QoS page will look somewhat like [image: this one], which is taken from my router, a different model by Linksys. I use this because the images in the User Manual of your router, referred to above, are terribly blurred.

Comment: Hi MariusMatutiae, thanks for your answer. I already have QoS enabled and have a specific ip added to lowest priority because I suspected torrent use. but can bandwidth hogging cause the router webinterface to become unavailable?

Comment: It can slow it down, yes. Even a lot. I do not know the details of your network, but it is also possible, if your network is not really state of the art, that your LAN is congested by traffic. Other diagnostics you can employ are wireshark to check the statistics of traffic, or a simple file transfer inside your LAN, through two pcs connected or not by a switch (i.e., not passing thru the router!). The comparison should give you info on congestion of network vs congestion of router.